# how to remove IPV4 address port number using javascript

Tags: javascript, ip

I have a javascript array of IP addresses,but some of IP address contains prot number like this: 198.228.200.169:46835
how can I use a javascript function to remove port number like this: 
198.228.200.169

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can do something like this `ip = ip.replace(/:\d+$/, "")`

Comment: `ip.split(":")[0]`

Comment: @dandavis thank you so much!

Comment: @Titus Thank you so much!